Windows to Raspberry PI Model 5 Folder Sharing
I have a windows system sharing a file share to a Raspberry Pi model 5
I have no password set on this pc
when I leave the password blank and press enter
i get mount error (13) permission denied
If I try and create a share with a client who has a password i get error 115
progess: after adjusting the firewall i no longer get the 115 error
still however get the 13 error



Can you share your /etc/samba/smb.conf ?

Im new to this, Im not sure what ur asking

oh wait, the rpi isn't the server, ignore that.

haha yeah its windows to ras

im trying to use the ras os but if this gets too hard I might be forced to install winArm which im more familiar with

Not sure if it's a client or server problem, but I always have all sorts of issues when the Windows SMB server's user account doesn't have a password, and I always have to give that user a password just to make it work (even a simple one).

When I connect my Raspberry Pi OS SMB client to a Windows 10 SMB server I use the following command, which is similar to yours but not identical: sudo mount -t cifs -o username=ben,uid=ben //myserver.example.com/Ben /mnt/myshare (this prompts interactively for a password). The Operation now in progress error makes it look like something is stuck, if it were me, I would try running dmesg to see more detailed messages, or rebooting the Pi or Windows.

[43474.277075] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.1.103/Remote_Access
[43474.280614] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[43474.280624] CIFS: VFS: \192.168.1.103 Send error in SessSetup = -13
[43474.280636] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13

xxx@xxx:~ $ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=Main_Link,pass=q&yLC0es9a //192.168.x.xxx/Remote_Access ~/Desktop/share
[1] 12822
bash: yLC0es9a: command not found
xxx@xxxx:~ $ mount: bad usage
Try 'mount --help' for more information.

when i go to type the password it doesnt show me typing anything, no **** nothing

That is perfectly normal in any Linux. Just type it and press Enter.
